# TypeError when adding multiple widgets to layout using SimpleGui

Tags: python, python-3.x, layout, pysimplegui

(answered]
I'm learning SimpleGui and when adding multiple widgets to the layout the system gives me a TypeError. Here is my code for the layout

```
layout = [
[sg.Text("I have no idea what i am doing")]

[sg.Text("i wanna make games and stuff")]
]
```

I'm using version 3.10.0 of python if that helps

Comment: What is the full error that you get?

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Text

Comment: Added this error to the PySimpleGUI documentation in a new "Troubleshooting" section, hoping that searches for the error will result in hits in the main doc.  If it's of any help, I make this same error frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a comma between your two lists:

```
layout = [
    [sg.Text("I have no idea what i am doing")],
    [sg.Text("i wanna make games and stuff")]
]
```

The error you get (`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Text`) is because the python interpreter thinks you're trying to index into the first list with your second list.